# Prove that the orthocentre and circumcenter in a triangle are Isogonal conjugate.

Tags: geometry

Prove that the orthocentre and circumcenter in a triangle are Isogonal conjugate.

For a acute triangle it is sth clear it just needs to draw circumscribed circle and measure the angles.But I can't prove it in an obtus triangle even in drawing it seems wrong.Any solutions?

Comment: A point and a line cannot be isogonal conjugates; only two points can be isogonal conjugates. What is the case is that the orthocentre is the isogonal conjugate of the circumcentre.

Comment: Yea I write wrong now how to prove in obtuse triangle?